# How to generate PDF after editing and removing content in the puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, headless

How to generate PDF after editing and removing content in the puppeteer?

Hello, I'm trying to create a pdf with specific content by editing the content returned by the puppeteer.

PDF is not generated with new content.

Could anyone help?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://www. site .com');
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    let image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[4];
        image.parentNode.removeChild( image );
    let name = document.querySelector('.name');
    name.innerHTML = 'changeName';
  });
  await page.pdf({path: 'file.pdf', format: 'A4'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem: everything is working as expected here, and the PDF file is generated with the updated DOM.

Comment: Did you do something different?
I do not understand why it does not work for me.

Comment: I queried `example.com`, changed the whole body to a random string, and printed the PDF like you did.

Comment: I was able to remove a tag. But I still can not change.

Comment: Can you provide the script with the intended URL so that it can be tested reliably?

Comment: As told by @vsemozhetbyt : post the whole script on a public site, there are two cases:
• 1: if your script doesn't work on a public page we can inspect and it and make some tests all our own (instead of trying to replicate your issue on another page that's is time-consuming and useless because the context changed)
• 2: if your script works on another page... it could help you find the issue or at least give us some more detailed hints

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = document.querySelector('.name');
        name.innerHTML = 'changeName';
```

to

```
let name = document.querySelector('.name')[3];
        name.innerHTML = 'changeName';
```

Comment: What do you mean by this answer, Marcelo? Why `document.querySelector('.name')[3]`? And how can there be 4 or them if querySelector [only returns the first result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)?